# Get most recent product's price combined with a search bar and order dropdown RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join, include, nested

I have a products list with a search bar and order options.

A product has many prices because I created a table called "prices" with a historical record, and the most recent price is the current price.

The products list is in the Product model index and the code is the following:

```
def index
  scope = Product
  # Search bar keywords
  if params[:search]
    scope = scope.search(params[:search])
  end
  # Order by dropdown selected option
  if params[:ordering] && ordering = ORDERS[params[:ordering].to_i]
    scope = scope.order(ordering)
  end
  @products = Product.all.order('id DESC')
end
```

I tried to add the following line, but this code repeat the products for each price in the table:

```
@products = Product.all.joins(:prices).order('id DESC')
```

I want a result like:

[image]

I don't have idea how to do joins or includes in rails.

Updates ------------------------

Schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150803051215) do

  create_table "prices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id", limit: 4
    t.decimal  "price",                  precision: 10
    t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
    t.string   "comment",    limit: 255
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
    t.boolean  "published"
  end

end
```

Actually, `@products.each do |product|`

Thanks.

Comment: your index action will always return the last line, so it does not care about `scope` variable - why do you have it (may be you use it somewhere in view - that's fine then)? Also I have no slightest clue, what this line `if params[:ordering] && ordering = ORDERS[params[:ordering].to_i]` is meant to do. You probably don't realize, that in `ordering = ORDERS ...` you actually perform assigning, not checking.

Comment: How are you iterating through `@products` to generate the HTML? `@products.find_each` or `@products.each`?

Comment: Could you also include your `schema.rb` for the `products` and `prices` tables?

Comment: Please, check the updates

Comment: if you want unique products through this line `Product.all.joins(:prices).order('id DESC')` add `.uniq` to the end that will give you unique records. Secondly `scope = scope.order(ordering)` and `scope = scope.search(params[:search])` will set the the results in `scope` and `Product.all.joins(:prices).order('id DESC')` is setting the products in `@products`. so your search will never work bcoz in view you are traversing `@products` rather than using the output of search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful way to do this is to, in addition to your `has_many :prices` relation, add a `has_one :current_price` relation to your Product model so that you can easily grab the current price. It's a bit tricky to define that relationship as a scope (it's easy in code, but we want this to be a proper Rails scope for a reason I'll reveal next). One way to do it is like so:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices
  has_one :current_price, -> {
    where('prices.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM prices p2 WHERE product_id = prices.product_id)') 
  }, class_name: 'Price'
end
```

Then, you can take advantage of Rails' `.includes` method to join that scope onto your Products when querying in your controller:

```
@products = Product.includes(:current_price).all
```

In your view, this is now easy and efficient:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.name %>, current price: <%= product.current_price.price %>
<% end %>
```

However, the definition of that `current_price` relation is a bit janky. Another simpler option, and still pretty efficient if you don't have many prices per product is to just load all the prices via `.includes` and find the recent one in Ruby:

```
@products = Product.includes(:prices).all
```

Then, in your view:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.name %>, current price: <%= product.prices.max_by(&:created_at) %>
<% end %>
```

This would also make it easy to show the lowest historical price, starting price, or any other info about the past prices of the product in the same view.

Comment: I don't understand how you print the result in the view

Comment: I got this error: undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass

Comment: If any of your products *don't* have any price records, the `.current_price` relation will be nil and thus you need to guard against that. The easiest way is like so: `current price: <%= product.current_price.try(:price) %>`

Comment: Lol, yes. That's it. Solved. tyvm